# Qt Data Model With Two Different Views

Tags: c++, qt

All, I am having trouble determining a good way to handle this.  I have a Data Model, which we will call `MyData`.  I have modelled my data as a `QObject` and thus it has signals and slots.

To modify any data in the model, you can either connect to its slots, or directly call the slots.  When that modification occurs, the model signals that its data has changed. eg:

```
class MyData : public QObject
{
   ...
public slots:
     void AddPoint(QPointF);

signals:
     void AddedPoint(QPointF);
};

void MyData::AddPoint(QPointF p)
{
    //added the point
    emit AddedPoint(p);
}
```

Now my views are two seperate things:

1. I have a `QGraphicsView`which represents the point using `QGraphicsEllipseItem`
2. I have a `QListView` which uses a `QAbstractItemModel` to list the points.

I sync these two graphical views using signals and slots (I subclasses QGraphicsItem to inherit from QObject).

**The question:** When a table makes the change, it signals `MyData`, which in turn signals `AddedPoint` which is connected to the QGraphicsView.  **However**, `MyData::AddedPoint` is also connected to the table, and thus two identical points are added when it attempts to sync.  Could anyone offer any advice on how to proceed?

---

My thoughts and ideas so far:

- I could check if the point exists, and prevent repeats.  Works great for insertions, not so great for removal and updating.
- **What I think is best the best approach:** In the `MyData` slots, block the sender() for a second, then unblock.

---

**Edit:** `MyData` is really a "controller/interface" class, the real model uses OpenCV types and as thus I would like to keep it separated from the Qt architecture.

Comment: Have you looked at Qt proxy models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could derive from `QAbstractListModel` like this:

```
class MyData : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum CustomRoles {
        PositionRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        BoundingRectRole
    };
    MyData(QObject *parent = 0) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
    {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[PositionRole] = "Position";
        roles[BoundingRectRole] = "BoundingRect";
        setRoleNames(roles);
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const
    {
        return points.count();
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
    {
        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() > points.count())
             return QVariant();

         const QGraphicsEllipseItem &p = points[index.row()];
         QVariant actualData;
         if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
             actualData = "some point";
         else if (role == PositionRole)
             actualData = p.scenePos();
         else if (role == BoundingRectRole)
             actualData = p.boundingRect();

         return actualData;
    }

public slots:
    void addPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        QGraphicsEllipseItem *it = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0,0, 5, 5);
        it->setPos(x,y);
        points << it;
        endInsertRows();
    }

private:
    QVector<QGraphicsEllipseItem*> points;
};
```

Now you can add this model simply to your QListView and in your `QGraphicsScene` connect to the `rowsInserted(...)` and/or `rowsRemoved(...)` signal of the model.

I also can recommend reading [this](http://invalidmagic.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/qgraphicsscene-used-as-a-qabstractitemview-iii/)

Comment: This was very helpful, I took a very similar approach.